# TCP sending/receiving missing bytes

Tags: java, c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I am using C# to create a server software for Windows and Java to create the client software.
It works fine most of the time, except for those few exceptions that I don't understand.

I am generally using .ReadLine() and .WriteLine() on both ends to communicate, unless I try to send binary data. That's when I write and read the bytes directly.
This is how the software is supposed work:

1. Client requests the binary data
2. Server responds with the length of the binary data as a string
3. Client receives the length and converts it into an integer and starts reading (length) bytes
4. Server starts writing (length) bytes

It works in most cases, but sometimes the client app doesn't receive the full data and blocks. The server always immediately flushes after writing data, so flushing is not the problem.

Furthermore I've noticed this usually happens with larger files, small files (up to ~1 MB) usually are not a problem.

**NOTE** It seems like the C# server does send the data completely, so the problem is most likely somewhere in the Java code.

**EDIT** - Here are some logs from the client side

**Working download**: [pastebin.com/hFd5TvrF](http://pastebin.com/hFd5TvrF)

**Failing download**: [pastebin.com/Q3zFWRLB](http://pastebin.com/Q3zFWRLB)

It seems like the client is waiting for 2048 bytes at the end (as it should be, as `length - processed = 2048` in this case), but for some reason the client blocks.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Below are the source codes of both server and client:

C# Server:

```
public void Write(BinaryWriter str, byte[] data)
{
    int BUFFER = 2048;
    int PROCESSED = 0;
    // WriteString sends the String using a StreamWriter (+ flushing)
    WriteString(data.Length.ToString());
    while (PROCESSED < data.Length)
    {
        if (PROCESSED + BUFFER > data.Length)
            BUFFER = data.Length - PROCESSED;

        str.Write(data, PROCESSED, BUFFER);
        str.Flush();

        PROCESSED += BUFFER;
    }
}
```

Java Client:

```
public byte[] ReadBytes(int length){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    int PROCESSED = 0;
    int READBUF = 2048;
    TOTAL = length;
    progress.setMax(TOTAL);
    InputStream m;
    try {
        m = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        while(PROCESSED < length){
            if(PROCESSED + READBUF > length)
                READBUF = length - PROCESSED;

            try {
                PROCESSED += m.read(buffer, PROCESSED, READBUF);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            XPROCESSED = PROCESSED;
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // Removed because of sensitive data
    }

    return decryptData(buffer);
}
```

Comment: In the Java client, what are the values for `PROCESSED` as you go through the loop? I'm interested in this because I'm curious why it ends 2048 bytes short when reading 10,000 bytes. I would expect it to have 1808 to read the last time it goes through the loop since it is reading 2048 bytes in each iteration.

Comment: @Poosh The 10,000 bytes was an example. I'm not on my PC right now so I can only give you estimated values, I'll comment again with the exact values later. The PROCESSED value always gets incremented by either 1440 or 2048, at the end it only gets incremented by ~700. At that point there are exactly 2048 bytes left to read, but as said, they don't arrive at the client.

Comment: UPDATE: Here are some logs:
Working download: https://pastebin.com/hFd5TvrF

Failing download: https://pastebin.com/Q3zFWRLB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a fix. As of now, the server sends the length and right after sends the byte array. For some reason this does not work.

So what I've changed is:

1. Send length **and wait for the client to respond with "OK"**
2. Start writing bytes

Not sure why, but it works. Ran it in a `while(true)` loop and it's been sending data 1000 times in 4 minutes straight and no problems, so I guess it's fixed.